# alternative column data type for REAL in MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, types

if I want to change a column data type from **REAL** to something else, like **NUMERIC**,
 what data type and precision I should use? **i.e. NUMERIC(?,?)**

please help~~ thank you.

this is what data I have in current column with data type REAL.

```
0.5
0.0086
2E-07
NULL
4
0.5
0.00375
1E-07
```

I need get exactly same value as usual when doing query, 
but since php driver have some problem with the REAL data type, 
I cannot use REAL anymore.

I tried with a new column in float,
I use update sql clause to copy value to the new column
and the new column shown exactly as I queried in PHP...   :-(

and it's annoying, because if I insert 16.7 into the REAL column,
I got 16.7 in SMS, 16.700000762939 in PHP query.

that's why I trying to find a alternative data type.

Thank you all in advanced.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to solve it from the wrong side? What about getting deeper into and explaining the problem that php driver has?

Comment: You can use the `FLOAT(M,D)` datatype... it's similar to `REAL` . actually even better.

Comment: @Tzar, that's mysql syntax for float and not SQL Server.

Comment: @Rahul Oops.. Sorry. Missed that! Edit: `FLOAT(n)` .. :)

Comment: Andrius, here is my php driver issue, FYI.
http://goo.gl/nmvn28

Comment: @Tzar, thank you, I'm trying using FLOAT, get u guys back soon.

Comment: If `REAL` is causing problem then `Float` will not be of help as well. By MSDN Real is the synonym for `Float(24)` where 24 is the representation bits.

Comment: Well, it is specific to datatypes.. So might work..
`REAL` has been derived from `FLOAT` itself... `FLOAT` is a more broader datatype.. and might have retained compatibility.

Comment: Nope, the weird thing is...I add a float column in original table, and use update clause to copy value to the new float column, then I got
0.45(in REAL) into 0.449999988079071, weather check in SMS or php query...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the exact values then stay away from float datatype as it is an Imaginary or Approximate representation of the number. Therefore using Float datatype you can get slightly different results then expected.

Use one of the NUMERIC or DECIMAL datatype. Which are only datatype allows you to store fractional values with exact numeric representation (Debateable but somewhat exact). :)

Read here [`MSDN Documentation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) to learn more about different Datatypes in Sql Server.

Comment: so, what would that be if using NUMERIC, without lose precision?
a thousand thanks~

Comment: Read the MSDN documentation to decide what is best for you. With NUMERIC or DECIMAL both you have the option to set the precision and scale, DECIMAL(p,s) or NUMERIC(p,s). Precision is the total number of digits in a value and scale is the digits after decimal point, e.g   10.001   has the Percision of 5 and scale 3. now you decide what precision is required to hold your data. Hope it helps and if the answer is helpful please accept it :)

Comment: the purpose I open this question is need suggestion of the (p,s) for REAL, I cannot decide or understand mssql(MSDN) definition, shamed that I cannot find the answer of equation of REAL = NUMERIC(p,s), what number is correct **p** and **s**.... please help...

Comment: The datatype equliant to REAL is float, But in your question you have mentioned that you want an exact value. If you go for REAL equilant which is float, it is not exact value and you will get unexpected results. Float values are only accurate to 17 decimal places after that any digits are arbitrary or approximate. Or do you want an exact value datatype. Which I have already mentioned it is NUMERIC or DECIMAL.

Comment: I have already explained you what Precision and Scale is. Investigate your data find the values with highest Precision and Scale and set those values to your New Column’s Datatype. I cannot possible be more clear about what I am saying here.